# How to scrape whole table( instead of first ten rows) from website with Kimono Labs

Tags: javascript, css, web-scraping, kimono

Im using Kimono labs to create an Api to scrape the data in this table from [this website](http://www.superkoora.com/en/competition-players-st/3/season:2002-team:2), however the website by default shows the first 10 rows only instead of all rows, so my api provides me with only 10 rows. Is there a way to make it parse all the table rows?

-- and that's one of the columns css selector

```
div.dataTables_wrapper > table.display.dataTable > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2).table_number
```

Comment: Did [this](https://help.kimonolabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/203274990-Crawl-pages-via-following-a-next-page-or-more-link) not work? Why?

Comment: Im not sure if I should feel dumb or think of you as a hero. Thank you! Can you post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Posted as an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't tried, but you really really should Google first. Found this: https://help.kimonolabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/203274990-Crawl-pages-via-following-a-next-page-or-more-link (from comment, you said to post as an answer)

In case the link goes dead:

1. Finish your API for the first page.
2. Click [image: Book icon] in the toolbar.
3. Click the next page/more link on the page. It should be highlighted gray.
4. When you save, select the maximum number of pages.